# React Native, Node js authentication

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, passport.js

What are the best libraries should I be using for node js + react-native authentication?
I was using passport local strategy with ejs templates for the login/register page because I was building a web app.
Now I am working on mobile application, I don't know how this is going to work on a mobile app.
Any ideas on how can I start this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is how I implement authentication in my react-native applications with node js backend. I use [jwt tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction), where I store the user's token inside the device using [expo's secure storage](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) library. Then following the recommended auth flow by react-native-navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/), whenever the app starts I check whether the token is present and return corresponding navigation stack. Refer to the code below for implementation.

**LoginScreen.js/RegisterScreen.js**

```html
//...

// Get token from your backend and save it in secure storage
const userToken = request.data.token
try {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("token", userToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
 }
 
 // ...
```

**App.js**

```html
export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState();
  
  // Fetch token and set state
  const restoreUser = async () => {
     const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("token")
     setUserToken(token)
  }
  
  if (!isReady)
    // Show splash screen while checking for userToken
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={restoreUser}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  
  return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {userToken == null ? (
      // No token found, user isn't signed in
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignInScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Sign in',
          // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
          // You can remove this if you want the default 'push' animation
          animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      // User is signed in
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
  
}
```

On the backend take a look at [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) npm package to see how to create jwt tokens. Goodluck!